# In Django, how to extract ID attribute from html Input tag, WITHOUT using django forms

Tags: html, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Suppose I’m wanting to extract some data from an html form on POST event, NOT in a django form.

In my views.py I can call “request.POST” and I get a dictionary of “name and value”. But in this case the names are all the same.

Is there a way that I can get the “id” instead of the name for example? w/o changing the html in the template ?

Pretty much a rookie here, don’t be too harsh on me

Here’s a snippet of the django template :

```
<!-- Radio Buttons -->
            <div class="form__group">
              <div class="form__radio-group">
                <input class="form__radio-input" type="radio" id="year1" name="year">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="year1">
                  <span class="form__radio-button"></span>
                  1st year
                </label>
              </div>

              <div class="form__radio-group">
                <input class="form__radio-input" type="radio" id="year2" name="year">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="year2">
                  <span class="form__radio-button"></span>
                  2nd year
                </label>
              </div>

              <div class="form__radio-group">
                <input class="form__radio-input" type="radio" id="year3" name="year">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="year3">
                  <span class="form__radio-button"></span>
                  3rd year
                </label>
              </div>

              <div class="form__radio-group">
                <input class="form__radio-input" type="radio" id="year4" name="year">
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="year4">
                  <span class="form__radio-button"></span>
                  4th year
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: No, this is how the HTML forms are defined to work: it sends a POST request with name/value pairs. You can write some JavaScript that for example does a certain translation, but that would probably be bad design. Why do you use the sane mane in the first place?

Comment: You could simply use `value="year1"`, etc. in the `<input>`s as well.

Comment: Thanks that last comment is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: As for the name it's sort of a hack. We're using checkboxes to be able to stylize radio buttons. They look like radio buttons, but they're actually checkboxes. Using the same name makes it so you can't click more than one at the time

Comment: perhaps you can implement your own widget for this (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/). Yes that will take some work, but perhaps later it will pay off if you need this often?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, I've solved this by using "value=1", as suggested by WillemVanOnsem in the comments, as such:

```
        <!-- Radio Buttons -->
            <div class="form__group">
              <div class="form__radio-group">
                <input class="form__radio-input" type="radio" id="year1" name="year" value=1>
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="year1">
                  <span class="form__radio-button"></span>
                  1st year
                </label>
              </div>

              <div class="form__radio-group">
                <input class="form__radio-input" type="radio" id="year2" name="year" value=2>
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="year2">
                  <span class="form__radio-button"></span>
                  2nd year
                </label>
              </div>

              <div class="form__radio-group">
                <input class="form__radio-input" type="radio" id="year3" name="year" value=3>
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="year3">
                  <span class="form__radio-button"></span>
                  3rd year
                </label>
              </div>

              <div class="form__radio-group">
                <input class="form__radio-input" type="radio" id="year4" name="year" value=4>
                <label class="form__radio-label" for="year4">
                  <span class="form__radio-button"></span>
                  4th year
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
```

The POST request sends out the value (ie: 1 for year 1), which is what I wanted to accomplish!